# SPSS: Syntax for Calculating FSCORE from rotated factors

Tags: matrix, rotation, spss, factor-analysis

I found the proper syntax to import my centriod factor extraction into SPSS and rotate it. (The semi-bumbling tale is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833145/reading-centroid-extracted-factor-matrix-into-spss-for-rotation-analysis).

The next issue is this: because of limitations in SPSS on what subcommands can be used when reading a matrix in (only /ROTATE and /EXTRACTION are permitted), I can't get the factor scores. SPSS displays this error:

"Factor scores cannot be computed with matrix input."

I still need to find a way to get the FSCORE of the newly rotated factors of each factor for all cases by running a regression using the newly rotated factors and saving the regression values as a new variable (/SAVE REG(ALL).

Ideas are welcome. Thank you for your expertise!

**Assets:** Dataset A of 36 cases and 74 variables (the basis of the centriod factor extraction); centriod factor extraction matrix

**Here's the SPSS syntax that almost does what I need** - except it uses PCA extraction instead of centroid.

```
FACTOR 
   /VARIABLES VAR00001 VAR00002 VAR00003 VAR00004 VAR00005 VAR00006 VAR00007 VAR00008 VAR00009 VAR00010 VAR00011 VAR00012 VAR00013 VAR00014 VAR00015 VAR00016 VAR00017 VAR00018 VAR00019 VAR00020 VAR00021 VAR00022 VAR00023 VAR00024 VAR00025 VAR00026 VAR00027 VAR00028 VAR00029 VAR00030 VAR00031 VAR00032 VAR00033 VAR00034 VAR00035 VAR00036 VAR00037 VAR00038 VAR00039 VAR00040 VAR00041 VAR00042 VAR00043 VAR00044 VAR00045 VAR00046 VAR00047 VAR00048 VAR00049 VAR00050 VAR00051 VAR00052 VAR00053 VAR00054 VAR00055 VAR00056 VAR00057 VAR00058 VAR00059 VAR00060 VAR00061 VAR00062 VAR00063 VAR00064 VAR00065 VAR00066 VAR00067 VAR00068 VAR00069 VAR00070 VAR00071 VAR00072 VAR00073 VAR00074 
   /MISSING LISTWISE 
   /ANALYSIS VAR00001 VAR00002 VAR00003 VAR00004 VAR00005 VAR00006 VAR00007 VAR00008 VAR00009 VAR00010 VAR00011 VAR00012 VAR00013 VAR00014 VAR00015 VAR00016 VAR00017 VAR00018 VAR00019 VAR00020 VAR00021 VAR00022 VAR00023 VAR00024 VAR00025 VAR00026 VAR00027 VAR00028 VAR00029 VAR00030 VAR00031 VAR00032 VAR00033 VAR00034 VAR00035 VAR00036 VAR00037 VAR00038 VAR00039 VAR00040 VAR00041 VAR00042 VAR00043 VAR00044 VAR00045 VAR00046 VAR00047 VAR00048 VAR00049 VAR00050 VAR00051 VAR00052 VAR00053 VAR00054 VAR00055 VAR00056 VAR00057 VAR00058 VAR00059 VAR00060 VAR00061 VAR00062 VAR00063 VAR00064 VAR00065 VAR00066 VAR00067 VAR00068 VAR00069 VAR00070 VAR00071 VAR00072 VAR00073 VAR00074 
/PRINT INITIAL CORRELATION SIG DET INV REPR AIC EXTRACTION ROTATION FSCORE 
/FORMAT BLANK(.544) 
/CRITERIA FACTORS(6) ITERATE(80) 
/EXTRACTION PC  <---Here's the rub.
/CRITERIA ITERATE(80) DELTA(0) 
/ROTATION OBLIMIN 
/SAVE REG(ALL) 
/METHOD=CORRELATION.
```

Answer (score 0):

I referred to the MATRIX command in my reply to your other post (Rotations).  You will need to research the appropriate equations for performing this calculation and set up the matrix algebra within a  MATRIX END - MATRIX code block.  Easy once you have the math right.  I'm too busy/lazy to research and write it but this should provide a fertile lead.

Comment: Hi David. I had to take a break to work on other projects, but I wanted to thank you for your suggested lead (which I'm not sure I understand). Even without inputing the algorithm as (I think?) you suggested, I traveled further down the road. I managed to get the factor scores (FSC) for each variable. I need to remember where I was with this and update my question.